# Basic MOSFET small signal model with no load and Rd

Tags: mosfet, electrical, small-signal

I've come across the most basic small signal model of the MOSFET. We have a NMOS whose drain is connected to Vdd= 5V and source is grounded. We also have biased gate with a DC 2V. Suppose the condition for saturation is met.

Now what my confusion is when we hook up a small signal voltage to the gate of NMOS, 0.01vpp sine(or any small signal to considerably affect the output swing), the output would be vds= -gm* ro*vgs (all are small signal voltages). So basically our Vout= Vds must be swinging(let's say 4V-6V) with DC at 5V. But here, our Vdd(and hence the Vds) is *fixed at 5V* (with no AC) as provided by the supply.

Isn't it contradicting with the small-signal model? How is KVL satisfied? Also even if we assume that Vds is swinging(from 4V to 6V), is there any drop in the connecting wires to satisfy KVL? But I'm assuming the wires have 0 resistance and are very small to avoid any resistance.

[image] [image: small signal model]

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You said the saturation is met with Vgs = 2V, so you should not expect any noticeable swing with so small the 0.01Vpp sine signal. I think perhaps you can try (1) not to go into the saturated region, and use a big signal (2). You may like to take 2N7000 to clarify your argument: (1)"2N7000 N-Channel Small Signal MOSFET 200 mAmps, 60 Volts, Rs(ON) 5Ω":
https://www.onsemi.cn/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF. Cheers.

Comment: But actually I am not too sure how to bias an Enhanced mode N-Type MOSFET in "***A Class Mode***" for amplification. Ref: "Enhancement-mode N-Channel MOSFET": 
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_6.html.

Comment: @tlfong01 we expect a very high gain(~10 dB)  in saturation with a small change in vgs due to very large *ro* in our small-signal model. My question is not about gain. I need clarification regarding the contradiction that arose due to the small-signal model. Even if we expect Vout to swing even 0.1V at fixed 5V DC due to gain, it violates KVL.

Comment: @MrityunjaySharma There's no violation. You have placed a voltage supply (taken to be ideal, but not really) across **D** and **S**. The variations placed at **G** (relative to **S**) merely adjust the current sink in the model. What's the problem you see with that? (\$V_\text{DS}\$ is fixed but the current varies a little.)

Comment: @jonk I understand that Vds is fixed and the current varies a little. But what about the  **vds = -gm* ro* vgs**, isn't vds supposed to change with varying vgs if we look into small-signal model as provided by theory?

Comment: @MrityunjaySharma Where does the small model say *"vds = -gm\* ro\* vgs?"* Do you see a voltage source where I see a current sink?

Comment: @jonk in the figure i've provided above, if we draw the equivalent ss model (shorting DC and keeping only AC), we have a current source (-gm* vgs) and a resistance ro in parallel with it, thus vds appears to be **-gm * ro* vgs** . Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm just doing what theory says.

Comment: @MrityunjaySharma Yes, you can re-Thevenize that Norton pair if you want. But then you have to include the resistor, ***in series***!! Which avoids any problems with KVL or KCL. Do you not understand how that works?

Comment: @jonk what I'm trying to do is, I'm measuring the voltage across the DS terminal with a near-infinite resistance voltmeter. Or we can have a near infinite load Rl. So, the voltage appears across it would definitely be    -gm * ro * vgs. This was about small signal part. Now we have already 5V DC across it. Won't the net Vds theoritically be 5(DC) +- some AC mV? But it is supposed to be ONLY 5V DC(which is the same as supply voltage)(practically)

Comment: @MrityunjaySharma You may have a very confused vision of things in your head that isn't reality. To be honest, I'm not sure what's wrong with your mental vision. It is wrong, though. You should agree with me because you've already admitted a fundamental conflict in your thinking process that you cannot seem to resolve -- you see two things which cannot both be simultaneously true. And so you have a problem. But I don't see any problems at all and there's no conflict spelled out by the model I have in my head. So I think you need to find what's broken in the way you think about this.

Comment: @jonk thanks a ton! I was doing a mistake. Instead of shorting it, I was doing it open. Now I know  how ss vgs comes out to be 0 hence Vout is maintained at a constant 5V. Don't know if this silly question should be deleted or not!

Comment: @MrityunjaySharma No question is silly. But since there's no answer to select, feel free to delete it. I'd suggest you keep it here except that you are the first person I've seen confused in just this way. So it's probably not terribly needed here. But it is also your question and you have every right to keep it around if you want, too. Someone might pop in here and post a really nice overall answer! So perhaps consider keeping it, too. It's your call.